# Not in stalemate, but why is this a draw?

Tags: endgame, stockfish, draw, rook-endgame

I was practicing with stockfish level 8, having two rooks in the endgame whereas stockfish has only one. At the 78th move, it was declared as a draw. But, it was not a stalemate. Can anyone please help me, finding out why is this a drawn match ?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The game ended because of the **50-Move-Rule**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifty-move_rule):

> The fifty-move rule in chess states that a player can claim a draw if no capture has been made and no pawn has been moved in the last fifty moves (for this purpose a "move" consists of a player completing their turn followed by the opponent completing their turn).

The last capture was made by white at move 28. (Rgxg6), so the game is declared a draw on move 78.

Comment: Appreciated, thank you for your efforts! Some day I will get the formatting right, I swear! :)

Answer (score 5):

You most likely played 50 moves without a capture or a pawn move. This is called the 50-move rule, which results in a draw.

Check back to around move 28. You should see the last capture/pawn move there.